# Issue with formatting date

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I know this question has been asked so many time and may be duplicate of some question, actually i am trying this for storing Date into array by converting them in String. I need that Value in NSDate format so i again convert that stored string into Date.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateformat =  [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateformat setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yy-hh-mm-ss"];

NSString *date  = [dateformat stringFromDate:datePicker.date];
[kAppDelegate.glbArrName   addObject:date];
```

But I get this output :

```
NSString *date = [kAppDelegate.glbArrDate objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSLog(@"Date of birth %@",date);

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yy-hh-mm-ss"];
NSDate *birthDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];

birthDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:date];

NSLog(@"Date of birth after formatting %@",birthDate);
```

Output is:

```
Date of birth 04-05-16-06-38-14
Date of birth after formatting 2016-04-05 01:08:14 +0000
```

Why it changes format, as i have done same as previous. please help me find out ..

Comment: Why bother converting to and from string?  An array can hold an `NSDate` without any problem.

Comment: actually i need formatting also, how to get NSdate directly from uipicker.date and also in formatted.. i actually get in string

Comment: Store the `NSDate` in your array. Don't convert it to a string until you need to display it to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You're rewriting the date string back into an NSDate, then printing out the NSDate, which defaults to the latter `2016-04-05 01:08:14 +0000` format as part of NSDate's `-description`.